# SQL Server: filter out results based on different data in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran into a issue with a query I'm creating.

The table looks like this:

```
LineId|Product|orderedQty|PickedQty|Operator|TimeFinised
------+-------+----------+---------+--------+-----------
     1|   1234|        60|       40|    Joe |     125546      
     2|   1234|        60|       18|  Benny |     120025
```

I would like to create a query that turns this into one result where the PickedQty are summed up. I would also like to only show the last operator that picked the items based on the column Timefinished.

The result should look like this:

```
Product|orderedQty|PickedQty|Operator
   1234|        60|       58|     Joe
```

Query so far:

```
 select
     product,
     orderedQty,
     cast(sum(m.PickedQty) as decimal(18,1)) as PickedQty,
 from 
     Lines
 group by 
     product, orderedQty
```

It's easy enough to summarize the PickedQty, but I have no idea how I can filter out the first operator.

Do anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Is it a coincidence that the name is on line 1?

Comment: Yeah it is coincidence

Answer (score 1):

Conditional aggregation may help:

```
select
   product,
   orderedQty,
   cast(sum(m.PickedQty) as decimal(18,1)) as PickedQty,
   MAX (CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN Operator END) AS Operator
from (
   SELECT 
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product, orderedQty ORDER BY TimeFinised DESC) AS Rn
   FROM (VALUES
       (1, 1234, 60, 40, 'Joe',   125546),      
       (2, 1234, 60, 18, 'Benny', 120025)
   ) v (LineId, Product, orderedQty, PickedQty, Operator, TimeFinised)   
) m
group by 
   product, orderedQty
```

Result:

```
product orderedQty  PickedQty   Operator
1234    60          58.0        Joe
```